# Include a field during unmarshal but not during marshal

Tags: json, go

I want to include the `password` field during the registration process but don't want to reveal it when user profile details are requested.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type User struct {
    UserName string `json:"username"`
    Password string `json:"-"`
}

func main() {
    data := []byte( `{"username": "username","password": "password"}`)
    user := User{}
    _ = json.Unmarshal(data, &user)

    user.Password = "password"
    user.UserName = "username"

    data, _ = json.Marshal(&user)
    fmt.Println(user)
    fmt.Println(string(data))
}
```

I want to do something like this:

`Unmarshal result`

```
{username password}
```

`Marshal result`

```
{"username":"username"}
```

Comment: why not use separate struct for user Registration?

Comment: One way to do this is by using the `,omitempty` option and every time before you run json.Marshal you set the password field to an empty string, this obviously is not ideal but it does what *you* want. To slightly automatize this you can declare a custom MarshalJSON method on your user struct that sets the empty string to the field before it delegates the job to json.Marshal, this way you're doing this only in one place. However, both these solutions are, in my opinion, more of a PITA than simply declaring a separate struct for the user signup as already suggested by @SauravPrakash.

Comment: Remove the password field from the user type and unmarshal twice, once into user and once into an ad-hoc type for the password. Then immediately hash the password. Pass users and password hashes separately to functions that need both. That way you avoid ever leaking the password by accident (in logs and such).

Answer (score 3):

You can write you own custom Json marshaller and unmarshaller for User struct.
Check this go playground link:
https://play.golang.org/p/ejmX9iDlvKk